# Quickbooks API and detecting deleted items

Tags: quickbooks

I'm using the Quickbooks XML API to import salesorders, items, and customers. Everything works great, however I haven't figured out how to handle things that are deleted in Quickbooks. Querying the imported data in my system is not an option because I have 20,000+ salesorders. My question is, does Quickbooks have a query for deleted items?

Comment: Is this QuickBooks ONLINE, or QuickBooks for WINDOWS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**QuickBooks for Windows:**

If you're using **QuickBooks for Windows**, then you can do a `TxnDeletedQueryRq` request to get a list of recently deleted transactions.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="9.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <TxnDeletedQueryRq>

            <!-- TxnDelType may have one of the following values: ARRefundCreditCard, Bill, BillPaymentCheck, BillPaymentCreditCard, BuildAssembly, Charge, Check, CreditCardCharge, CreditCardCredit, CreditMemo, Deposit, Estimate, InventoryAdjustment, Invoice, ItemReceipt, JournalEntry, PayrollLiabilityAdjustment [PRIVATE], PayrollPriorPayment [PRIVATE], PayrollYearToDateAdjustment [PRIVATE], PurchaseOrder, ReceivePayment, SalesOrder, SalesReceipt, SalesTaxPaymentCheck, TimeTracking, TransferInventory, VehicleMileage, VendorCredit -->

            <TxnDelType>Invoice</TxnDelType>
            <TxnDelType>ReceivePayment</TxnDelType>
        </TxnDeletedQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Example from here:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QbXML_for_Querying_for_Deleted_Objects
- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests

The full syntax with all options/flags you can set can be found in the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

**QuickBooks Online:**

If you're using **QuickBooks Online**, then you can use the CDC requests to poll for recently changed data, including things that have been deleted.

```
https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1234/cdc?entities=Class,Item,Invoice&changedSince=2012-07-20T22:25:51-07:00
```

Will return something like:

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2013-04-03T10:36:19.393Z">
   <CDCResponse>
    <QueryResponse>
        <Customer>...
        </Customer>
        ...
```

Some of which may have a `status="Deleted"` attribute to let you know it's been deleted.

Comment: This does answer the question, but the example is the wrong function. Somehow you listed the right one right above the wrong example.  you mentioned ... TxnDelRq deletes an item.  I pity the fool that just copies that example in and runs it on a transaction id.

Comment: @eteich I edited the example and link so they should be correct now. Good catch!

Comment: Palmer Cool deal... one thing that might be worthy of mention in this is the meta you can add to the <TxnDeletedQueryRq> tag.  Depending on implementation, things like request Id might need to be passed there.

Comment: Added link to the OSR, which is really what they should be referencing for all options/flags available.